# Regex in htaccessleads redirect to a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make my regex work in my htaccess to redirect every URL to my index.php but I get a 505 error

Here is my code

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase /MVC_PiePHP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/MVC_PiePHP/(webroot/.+|index.php|robots.txt)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA ,L]
```

It seems to be my RewriteRule that doesn't work, I don't get any errors when I remove it

Also a simple RewiteRule like this one works perfectly fine

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: `[QSA ,L]` should be `[QSA,L]` (no space)

Comment: It works perfectly fine now, thanks a lot!